# How could there be lightning if it was stolen?

Tags: percy-jackson

I'm currently listening to Percy Jackson and the Lightning Thief. There's a scene where Percy is being chased to Camp Half-Blood. And during this, there is a storm raging. Thunder, lightning, etc. But I'm confused. If the lightning bolt of Zeus was stolen, how was there able to be thunder and lightning while Percy heading to Camp Half-Blood?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Master Bolt](http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Bolt) stolen in The Lightning Thief is Zeus's symbol and is considered the most powerful weapon in the world. It does not, however, grant control over thunderstorms, lightning, etc. It is simply a high-yield explosive weapon (extremely high-yield as it tore the top off Mt. Etna). In fact, the Master Bolt is generally not be used in any case, barring dire need such as against world-ending foes. Whenever there needs to be lightning, Zeus uses numerous minor lightning bolts which are patterned off of the Master Bolt.

Comment: Do you have links or anything to cite, or is this something explained later on in the book?

Comment: This answer matches what I remember from the film version.  The Master Bolt isn't the *concept* of lightning, it's just a powerful weapon that takes the form of lightning.

Comment: The [Master Bolt](http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Bolt) is not a representation of lightning, only a weapon of incredible power, consider it a lightning bolt-shaped nuclear weapon in a can. And there's your link...

Comment: @MyCodeSucks - Having read the book last month, I can confirm that this description is accurate as far as the book goes.

Comment: @DVK: Good enough for me. Thanks. BTW, thank you guys for staying spoiler free, even though I didn't ask. Still doing the audio book of the first one.

Comment: @DVK: Okay, having just watched the opening of the movie, why did Zeus make a point out of there being no lightning during the storm, if the Master Bolt wasn't needed?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Well, since all lightning bolts are built using the Master Bolt, maybe his supply ran out and they couldn't make more because, well, no Master Bolt?

Comment: @Steam - because not-good movie scriptwriters?

Answer (score 2):

To add to Steam's direct answer, this is how ALL the gods' powers work.

Witness discussion Persy has with Apollo over the distinction of his chariot vs. the Sun being a giant ball of plasma. Apollo's point is that "Yes, the Sun is a giant ball of plasma. Boooooring. My chariot is more of a mythological construct, a cultural artefact of how humans percieve the Sun and its influence on them".